# Google Analytics virtual page view with gtag

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, virtual, dynamic-pages

I'm very new to Google Analytics.

How can I make a virtual pageview only for a dynamic page included in a HTML template?

Please just refer to my code below to know more details of the situation.

A dynamic page [Price Details] pops out when you press the button [Show Price].

URL or even template doesn't change when this dynamic output appears, because they both are in ONE template.

I'd like to count up how many people actually have seen [Price Details], so can anyone tell me how to get a virtual pageview only for the dynamic page?

I'm using gtag for your info.
I will appreciate so much any idea about this! Thanks!

```
<div class="section">
<a href="#" id="buttonSet" class="button"><span>Show Price</span></a>
</div>
・・・
・・・
bla bla
・・・
・・・
<header class="head">
    <p class="title">Price Details</p>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below *onclick* pageview trigger:

```
<a href="#" id="buttonSet" class="button" onClick="ga(‘send’, ‘pageview’, ‘/virtual/guides/download/social-media-guide.pdf’);><span>Show Price</span></a>
```

Comment: That isn't gtag, that's the analytics.js method.